# Place UITableViewCell beneath siblings

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to build a custom UITableView that acts in a similar way to the reminders app.

Instead of the top-most visible cell scrolling off the display, I want it to be covered by the next cell so the cells appear to stack on top of one another as you scroll.

Currently I am using:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

  let topIndexPath: NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows()?.first as! NSIndexPath

  let topCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(topIndexPath)

  let frame = topCell!.frame

  topCell!.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)
}
```

But the top cell is always above the second cell - causing the second cell to scroll under it.

Also if I scroll quickly this seems to misplace all of my cells.

**EDIT: Have fixed this. Answer posted below for future reference.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody searching this in the future.
Simply loop through all the visible cells and set their z position to their row number (so each cell stacks above the previous one).

The if statement tells the top cell to remain at the contentOffset of the scrollview and for all other cells to assume their expected position. This stops the other cells being offset if you scroll too quickly.

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

  // Grab visible index paths
  let indexPaths: Array = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows()!

  var i = 0
  for path in indexPaths {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path as! NSIndexPath)
    // set zPosition to row value (for stacking)
    cell?.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(path.row)

    // Check if top cell (first in indexPaths)
    if (i == 0) {
      let frame = cell!.frame

      // keep top cell at the contentOffset of the scrollview (top of screen)
      cell!.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x,
                                scrollView.contentOffset.y,
                                frame.size.width,
                                frame.size.height)
    } else {
      // set cell's frame to expected value
      cell!.frame = tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(path as! NSIndexPath)
    }
    i++
  }

}
```